# How to empty element correctly in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I'd like to have a page where user could input query string without input box, but some keys ( <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> ) have a special meaning **while** there is no input yet.

It works fine until I submit query string. After that I try to empty `<div>` where input was hold (as `$("#input").text('')` or `$("#input").empty()`), but it seems not being empty enough. When I try to use my special keys after emptying, it still behaves like there is some value in. Only **after** I press once more <kbd>backspace</kbd>, my original behavior recovers.

I post my code here below, but you can try it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw34cos6/1/):

**EDIT** Find out I can post snippets here:

```js
var basket = 0;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode;

  if (keycode === 8 && $("#input").text() !== '') {
    var input = $("#input").text();
    $("#input").text(input.slice(0, -1));
  }

  if (keycode === 13 && $("#input").text() !== '') {
    var query = $("#input").text();
    $("#body").append(`<p>search: ${query}</p>`);
    // submit search
  }
});

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var keycode = e.keyCode;
  var char = String.fromCharCode(keycode);
  console.log(keycode);
  console.log(char);

  if (keycode === 13) {
    $("#input").empty();
  }

  if ($("#input").text() === '') {
    console.log("empty: '" + $("#input").text() + "'");
    if (char === '+') {
      basket++;
    } else if (char === '-') {
      basket--;
    } else if (char === '=') {
      basket = 0;
    } else {
      $("#input").append(char);
    }
    $("#basket").text(basket);
  } else {
    var temp = $("#input").text();
    console.log("not empty: '" + temp + "'");
    $("#input").append(char);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input"></div>

<div id="basket"></div>

<div id="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just use `elem.innerHTML = "";` this makes it empty. but there could be more ways.

Comment: It has the same behaviour as mine. Maybe I have flaw in my code somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit, there was flaw in the logic. After emptying element the conditional (`if ($("#input").text() === '')`) saw it is empty and added last keystroke (<kbd>Enter</kbd>), so on next `keypress` it was not empty anymore. Simplest way was to clear `char` variable also:

```
  if ( keycode === 13 ) {
    $("#input").empty();
    char = '';
  }
```

Hope, this snippet above still helps someone in the future.